# Socket for 2 devices on same network not working

Tags: javascript, angular, sockets, ionic-framework, electron

I'm actually working on an ElectronJS Application and an Ionic App.

The Electron app has a Socket server (using SockJS) and the Ionic app the Socket client.

My problem is when i launch the two app on the same device, it's working fine, but, when the Electron App is launch on my computer and the Ionic app on my android device, it's not working.

I tried with my local IP, localhost, 0.0.0.0, 127.0.0.1. But no one works.

Electron :

```
const {ipcMain} = require('electron')
let app = require('express')();
const http = require('http').Server(app);
let io = require('socket.io')(http);

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log('socket connected');

    socket.on('disconnect', function () {
        console.log('socket disconnected');
    });

    socket.emit('text', 'wow. such event. very real time.');
});

var port = process.env.PORT || 9999;

http.listen(port, function(){
   console.log('listening in http://localhost:' + port);
});
```

Ionic :

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient  } from '@angular/common/http'; 
import { Socket, SocketIoConfig } from 'ngx-socket-io';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CoreService {
  config: SocketIoConfig
  private socket: Socket
  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { 
    this.config = { url: 'http://localhost:9999', options: { secure: true } };
  }

  connectSocket() {
    this.socket = new Socket(this.config)
    this.socket.connect()
    this.socket.on('text',(value) => {
      console.log(value)
    })
  }
}
```

If anyone can help me.

**EDIT 1**

I try much things. I have desactivate my firewall for testing and try this IP (Localhost, 0.0.0.0, local IP, 127.0.0.1) but no one works.

The communication works when i'm in the same computer (Ionic on emulator or web browser). But when i'm testing in my android device, it's not working. (I'm on the same network)

I have no error on ionic :

```
D/mali_winsys: EGLint new_window_surface(egl_winsys_display *, void *, EGLSurface, EGLConfig, egl_winsys_surface **, EGLBoolean) returns 0x3000
W/InputMethodManager: startInputReason = 1
I/HwSecImmHelper: mSecurityInputMethodService is null
I/HwSecImmHelper: mSecurityInputMethodService is null
I/HwSecImmHelper: mSecurityInputMethodService is null
I/HwSecImmHelper: mSecurityInputMethodService is null
I/HwSecImmHelper: mSecurityInputMethodService is null
I/HwSecImmHelper: mSecurityInputMethodService is null
```

And i'm now using Socket.io instead of SockJS, but still not working..

Comment: Have you checked firewall settings?

Comment: I tried with the local IP and change the port for 80. Still not working (port 80 is allowed by default ?)

Comment: No, the opposite actually, firewall will actually probably want to block port 80 the most.  `netstat -an` to see what's up.  Test with telnet first.

Comment: Yes you right, 80 isn't listenning. So, how i can open a port with my app and be sure that a user (who will download my app) got this port open too ?

Comment: That's a bigger platform-specific system administration question.  But for now, for the purposes of development, you can go back to using a high numbered port like 8000 or 9999 and just allow it in your firewall.

Comment: I don't know where is the problem, but nothing works.... I edited the post